# checking for duplicates after generating random alphanumeric string in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using this function:

https://www.devhut.net/2010/06/22/ms-access-vba-generate-a-random-string/

To create a random alpha numeric string through my form.

This needs to be unique so I need it to check for uniqueness in the column and regenerate a new string if it is not unique. I'm not married to this code if there is a better way to generate a string.

Comment: Do a DLookup() with the generated string.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how to do this?

Comment: Conditional code in a procedure where you call the function: `If IsNull(DLookup("fieldname", "tablename", "fieldname='" & GetRandomString(,,,) & "'")) Then`

Comment: @June7 it keeps returning an invalid syntax error    <br/>          <pre> <code> = If IsNull(DLookup("userentry", "tamountupd", "userentry='" & GetRandomStr(6,True,False,True) & "'")) Then

Comment: Works for me. Edit your question to post the complete calling procedure code.

Comment: @June7 are you running this in its own module or on the a default value of a text box?

Comment: The example I gave is VBA so it is in a general module. Won't work as expression in Default Value property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim Criteria As String
Dim NotFound As Boolean

Do
    RandomString = GetRandomString(StringLength, False, True, False)
    Criteria = "[YourField] = '" & RandomString & "'"
    NotFound = IsNull(DLookup("[YourField]", "[YourTable]", Criteria))
Loop Until NotFound
```